# Deserializing a class defined in a plugin

Tags: c++, plugins, deserialization

In my process I load plugins from which I get objects I use in the rest of the process.
This class inherits from `MyInterface` so serializing it is not a big deal.
I just implement a `virtual const unsigned char* Serialize()` method in it.
What I can't figure out is how I can deserialize it, since the deserialization method is supposed to be static, I can't do the same.
Must I expose a Deserialization method from the plugin DLL or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Show some actual code and context. This is unanswerable in it's current form.

Answer (score 0):

Whether or not you need to expose the `Deserialize` function in your DLL's exports depends on your application's design.  If you need clients to call the `Deserialize` function, then it needs to be exposed.

As far as how it works, `Deserialize` needs to have the same basic architecture as a [Factory Method](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C++_Programming/Code/Design_Patterns#Factory).  The serialized data needs to indicate what type of object it represents, in addition to all the goodies in the object.  Otherwise, the whoever calls `Deserialize` needs to know what kind of object is to be deserialized, but it sounds like this is not possible or desirable in your scenario.  If you store the object type as part of the serialized data, you can then `switch` on it in your `Deserialize` method, and construct the correct type of object.

Comment: ok, but if someone else writes the plugin, I have no idea what is inside the object he sends to me.